Docker - ASP.NET Core 8 Web API : the connection was reset
While my ASP.NET Core 8 Web API works fine on Windows in debug/release mode, I cannot make it work with Docker on linux.
I keep getting an error

The connection was reset

in my web browser.
I run the API on port 5063 as it is defined in the .NET Core project:
docker run -p 5063:5063 my-api -name test
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://[::]:8080
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: /app

The project is indeed listening:
netstat -tulnp | grep LISTEN

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5063            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::5063                 :::*                    LISTEN      -                   

How can I check the log files? Or get a command line?
I tried
docker run -it --rm my-api cmd

but it just runs the docker image

Note: although it says listening on 8080, nothing is listening there, browser does not respond either on that port
I've been trying
docker run -p 5063:8080 omp-ssp-api

and this works !
No idea why port 5063 is not working

How do you setup the port the app listens? Do you have a full [mre] you can share?

now it works, at first I was using port 8080 ... then I used 5063 as it was setup in the .ENT project

Your app is listening on port 8080 as you can see in the log message Now listening on: http://[::]:8080. Port settings in launchersettings.json only work when running from VS or another IDE.

yeah I assumed that at some point, but I also tried 8080:8080 at fisrt and it was not working, then suddenly, the same setup worked

this is one of those case where I started with a perfectly good setup but since it was not working I fiddled around loosing track
basically the app is listening on 8080 and at first I tried
docker run -p 8080:80 omp-ssp-api

instead of
docker run -p 80:8080 omp-ssp-api

